# Does Python Twisted work with wxPython?

Tags: python, wxpython, twisted

Am wondering does twisted framework work well with wxPython GUI framework. From the docs its seems like twisted does not support wxPython well. The example given seems to be a bit shy on the details.

- If not, what is the best way of using twisted with wxPython?
- Which other non-blocking event-driven networking framework can i use with wxPython?

Thanks

Gath

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? One's a network library one's a GUI library.

Comment: Build an app that has a GUI interface and a networking communication layer. The Network layer receives data/commands from the GUI interface and sends them to other applications within a network.

Comment: it seems like the serialport stuff doesnt work so well with the wxreactor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Twisted works with wxPython. I see a couple questions about that from time to time on the wxPython mailing list. Here are some links you might find helpful:

- http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/choosing-reactor.html
- http://wiki.wxpython.org/wxPythonAndTwisted
- http://code.activestate.com/recipes/181780-using-wxpython-with-twisted-python/

Comment: thanks, let me play around with the examples. Do they work well  with linux? Am testing on windows, but i know the actual deployment would be on linux.

Comment: I know wxPython does. I would be very surprised if Twisted doesn't. That package seems like a natural fit for Linux.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using wxPython with Twisted on Linux, Mac and Windows without any crazy things happening.

Comment: Thank you! Still deciding best cross platform wise way to create background app using Python. One question though, how do Twisted consume processor and memory?